# DRUPAL: Making Multiple Front Pages with same layout, but different content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

To start, I am a beginner in drupal, so any advice helps me out a lot.

My problem:

I am interning for a village hall and they want me to recreate their website for them using drupal. So far I have created a front page with a drop-down menu, slideshow, and quicktabs. What I want to do is create four menu buttons separate from the current drop-down (business, residential, government, visitors), and when someone clicks on them it takes them to the specific page, that has the same layout but different images on the slideshow and menu items on the drop-down.

For example, the landing page would be the default of business. So the slideshow, drop-down menu, and quicktabs would have things related to business. If someone clicked on residents, it would take them to the residents sections with the same layout, but different images in the slideshow, different items to click in the drop-down menu, and different tabs in the quicktab.

I have tried using views to do this, but I keep getting the feeling that this is not what I want. My idea was to manipulate the page.tpl.php, but then again I could be heading in the completely wrong direction.

Thanks for you help!!

![Screenshot][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIIXc.jpg "screenshot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is "answered" already, but I think I ran into a similar problem you ran into. The way that I fixed this was to manipulate the php page.tpl.php page and front-page.tpl.php. You can then customize the pages to your liking. If you google austin texas, you can see a website that did something to what you're looking for.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd think about this is, as you mentioned, to think of them as landing pages.

I'd create a content type called 'landing page'. I'd give that content type a image field with multiple values. Then you create a slideshow that uses that image field and have a drop down menu that uses the child menu items for the current node.

This then allows you to create any number of these landing pages as nodes, uploading images for each one individually and use the menu system to define what is available in the drop down.

Comment: Sorry if this is naive, but would I use taxonomy then in the menus so that they only pull the information tagged or is that not necessary?

Comment: Also, I am using the premium responsive theme if that helps at all, so there is already a slideshow on the front page

Comment: I'm not sure what taxonomy you already have in place or need?

I guess I was wondering if the menu hierarchy was all you needed to show which content should be included in the dropdown menu for each landing papge

Comment: So my ideal layout would consist of essentially four pages with identical layout but completely different content. Which would mean completely different images in the slideshow, completely different drop-down menu links, and completely different quick-tab selections. I edited the post to have a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Using [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context), [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta), and a base theme like [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) would be a way of approaching the 'landing page' issue.